# How to enable and create 2nd level subdomains with Apartment gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I'm quite noob in this:

**Question part 1:** As I understand then [FirstSubdomain](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/apartment/1.0.0/Apartment/Elevators/FirstSubdomain) class can be used to enable second level subdomains, but where and how should I declare it to enable it?

**Question part 2:** If you make a new schema with Apartment like this:

```
Apartment::Tenant.create 'newtenant'
```

then it gives you also a subdomain like `newtenant.myapp.com`. Is there a way to create 2nd level subdomains straight from the console or do I get something very wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing something important: you have to define subdomains through the DNS settings for your domain.

**Another tip**: use the lvh.me domain for local testing with subdomains. If you browse to `lvh.me:3000` you will actually browse to `localhost:3000`. If you browse to `sub.newtenant.lvh.me:3000` the same happens.

Comment: Possible, but at the moment all I need to do for a new first-level subdomain to work is create it from the console with `Apartment::Tenant.create 'yetanothertenant'` and add sth like `yetanothertenant.myapp.com` to my hosts-file on the proper line. Is there something similar I need to do with second level subdomains?

Comment: If you want to use your hosts file, you can just add ie. `sub.yetanothertenant.myapp.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling FirstSubdomain is an Apartment initializer job (`Apartment::Elevators::FirstSubdomain`) and question part 2 is basically answered in question- it works in my localhost just like that: `Apartment::Tenant.create 'newtenant'.

Question came up because a bit messy situation in developing with little custom-made system for reading tenant-name from url. That's why I thought my multi-level subdomains don't work.

I'll leave the question up just in case someone finds it (or answers) useful.